# How to format POST request using PHP curl methods?

Tags: php, php-curl

I'm trying to send a post request with this payload:

```
$request_content = [
    "data" => [
        [
            "sku" => "0987",
            "price" => $price,
            "category" => "moveis",
            "brand" => "bartira",
            "zip_code" => "07400000",
            "affiliate" => "google-shopping"
        ]
    ]
];
```

Since it's a post i set the `CURLOPT_POST` to true;

```
$encoded_request = json_encode($request_content);
$ch = curl_init("https://my-service/endpoint/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Authorization: Token my-token"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encoded_request);
```

The `$encoded_request` content shown in `print_r` is:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "sku": "0987",
        "price": "5.99",
        "category": "moveis",
        "brand": "bartira",
        "zip_code": "07400000",
        "affiliate": "google-shopping"
    }
]
}
```

If i use this content on the `Postman` i get the right response from the service that i'm requesting, but on my code i got the error;

> {"data":["This field is required."]}

Which configuration i'm missing on `curl_` to format the payload correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER and change your variable $request_content, something like this:

```
//set your data
$request_content = [
    "data" => [
      [
        "sku" => "0987",
        "price" => $price,
        "category" => "moveis",
        "brand" => "bartira",
        "zip_code" => "07400000",
        "affiliate" => "google-shopping"
      ]
    ]
];
$encoded_request = json_encode($request_content);

$ch = curl_init("https://my-service/endpoint/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encoded_request);

// Set HTTP Header for POST request 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Authorization: Token my-token',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($encoded_request)]
);
```

Comment: you forgot the "data" key but anyways, it works, i think that it was the "content-type" header that fixed it :)
Please fix your answer so i can mark it as solved